# HTTP2 Request doesn't follow redirects in JMeter 5.0

Tags: redirect, jmeter, jetty, http2, jmeter-5.0

I'm using the HTTP2 plugin for JMeter from Blazemeter and I'm unable to make the HTTP2 request follow the redirects. I tried checking the "Follow Redirects" box and "Synchronized Request" and it doesn't work.

I get the Response code: 301 & Response message: HTTP/2.0 301 Moved Permanently  and the location where it should redirect in the Response headers => "location".

I am trying to make a HTTP2 request to "www.aoro.ro" (GET https://www.aoro.ro/) which should redirect me to "https://www.notino.ro/" but does not follow the location it gets from the Reponse headers: 
HTTP/2.0 301 Moved Permanently
location: https://www.notino.ro/
and I'm stuck with this response and cannot use assertions based on the redirects.

I also tried to use "HTTP Header Manager" and send all the headers from the browser. I read that HTTP2 version of HTTP protocol is asynchronous and this may interfere with the redirect.

Do you know anything regarding the Redirecting on JMeter with HTTP2 plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm it's a bug of [HTTP2 Request](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/http2/README.md) that I reported here (as there is no issue reporting in their github):

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/ww-c5BkuRu4

What you can do is handle it yourself using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor):

[image: REE Config]

And add it like this:

[image: Test Plan]

Then use ${REDIRECT} in path field of another HTTP2 Request:

[image: Reuse variable]

Comment: Where's the bug report for this?  Not following redirect doesn't seem like a bug.  I certainly never want to auto follow redirect, especially in a controlled testing scenario like jmeter.

Comment: it’s a bug since there is a checkbox saying follow redirect while it’s not happening. Compare to core http request. The github repo has no issue report, so I reported it on jmeter-plugins google group.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and bug reporting. Tried to use regex on response headers and manually implement the "redirect" with the location and it works fine but this is a good termporary solution for a short JMeter script. I want to switch from HTTP1.1 to HTTP2 a complete scenario (login-search-add2basket etc) and manually redirect every request would put high load on the JVM. So hopefully your report on jmeter-plugins google group will be noticed @UBIKLOADPACK

Comment: Found out why it didn't Follow redirects, see below. @UBIKLOADPACK

Answer (score 2):

After a deeper research about the **blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler** I found out that the HTTP2 sampler request does not have the **followRedirects()** method implemented in the **HTTP2Request.class** file.

To get to this file you have to extract files from **jmeter-bzm-http2-1.4.jar** file from lib.ext folder and the .class files will be in **com\blazemeter\jmeter\http2\sampler** folder. After this step you have to decompile **HTTP2Request.class** file (did it using the online tool : https://devtoolzone.com/decompiler/java) and open it using Notepad++ / Sublime or any other program to see the script.

So until a new version of this plugin is released, Follow Redirects/ Autoredirect will not work (no implementation of it)