# Http2 Sampler plugin for JMeter with Redirects

Tags: jmeter, jetty, netty, http2, jmeter-plugins

Regarding this Question asked earlier: [HTTP2 Request doesn't follow redirects in JMeter 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173133/http2-request-doesnt-follow-redirects-in-jmeter-5-0) , do you know and/or used other HTTP2 plugin for JMeter that follows redirects the way it should when the checkbox for "Follow Redirects" is marked and has the option of using Assertions on those redirects? Already tried Jetty and Netty (the latter is 3y old).

Comment: Have you filed a bug with the apache-jmeter folks yet?  Jetty's HttpClient supports auto-redirect, so this is very much a bug on the apache-jmeter side.

Comment: @joakim-erdfelt, it's HTTP2Client, this is a 3rd party, not a JMeter core feature. And yes, I reported it.

Comment: Hi @JoakimErdfelt, as I said in the question is about the HTTP2 plugin, the HTTP1.1 works fine. I made two similar requests, one with HTTP2 and another with 1.1 version and captured all the packets send/received with Wireshark tool, and the HTTP2 sampler didn't redirect. I tried with "Follow Redirects"  and then with "Redirect Automatically" and none of them worked, meanwhile, the 1.1 version worked fine both ways. If you have other suggestions please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Jetty's HttpClient does HTTP/2 for JMeter, it's one of the options you can select ("Jetty" vs "Netty").  It offers both traditional HTTP/2 TLS/APLN connect and TLS+HTTP/1.1 + PRI connect to HTTP/2.